# How to get split metal plate effect?

Tags: texturing

[image: Matel Plate Effect]

Can anyone pls tell me how can I archive that kind of effect(shown in the picture) in Blender?

Comment: you could also try with a Normal Map, have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by modeling the whole object as one, and then as a final step I set up planes where I wanted cuts.

The add-on BoolTool lets you do a Slice operation which will quickly cut along a plane.

***Edit for Blender v2.91+:** *The addition of the exact solver has made this BoolTool function unreliable.  A workaround is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278669/110840).*

[image]

This was the result in rendered view:

[image]

It takes some planning with all-quad geometry.  Since you're dividing along a plane, you're essentially adding one loop cut somewhere which should lead to quads on either side.  There is a BIG problem if you have any poles.  It looks terrible.  For this object it wasn't a problem, it's modeled for subdivision and the pole is hidden.  With some planning I think the body of a rocket would be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help....

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You could also fake the slot with a normal map:

- Create a plane, create an edge loop (or as many as needed), bevel, extrude down, scale it a bit so that the vertical faces are a bit tilted:

[image]

- Switch to top view, choose a *Viweport Shading > Matcap > Normal* style:

[image]

- Hide the overlays, and in the header menu choose > *View > Viewport Render Image* (or render an image with the camera):

[image]

- Crop the image to keep the normal map only, in the *Shader Editor* upload it into an *Image Texture* that you plug into a *Normal Map* node that you plug into the *Normal* socket of your *Principled BSDF* (or other nodes):

[image]

- Here is what it gives in the 3D view in *Rendered* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help...