# Slice a shape with a plane

Tags: uv, edit-mode, bisect

I saw in speedrun by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gf8KEEgCh_k and I'm curious how he managed to cut the uv sphere into two using the plane.

Any suggestions are welcome

[image]

Comment: BoolTool addon has a slice mode that automates a bunch of functions that would normally be necessary to reproduce two separated pieces of a mesh.

Comment: That's true, but my concern is, after deforming the plane, the resulting split had edges of the plane.

Comment: You can use a plane for booltool, or at least it used to work.  I think I have an answer somewhere, hang on

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216334/110840

Comment: As long as the deformation comes from a modifier and not a shader tree, I think it should work

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to split, but I loose a half of it. I guess I'll check out how to use the Bool tool.

Comment: I suppose in that case it's easiest to duplicate the object and do the split twice, once on each object with the plane facing opposite directions

Comment: This seems to work well. I've managed to achieve it :)

Comment: if you want you can self-answer, or if not I can come up with something in the next few days

Answer (score 0):

It looks like since the *Boolean Modifier* had another solver option added, some functions in *BoolTool* are less predictable, or completely broken.  *Slice* is still usable, but it creates a duplicate object with the same mesh data, so it's unable to finish the operation

In this case a manual solution is easier to manage.

Start with your base object and a cutter plane, and run *Boolean -> Difference* on the two.

[image]

Then you can select both objects and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate.  When you duplicate objects that are associated with each other through a modifier like this, the modifiers' references are automatically set to the newly created objects, so that is already done for us.

Select Plane.001, tab into *Edit Mode* and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> -> *Flip* to flip the normal of the plane.  This reveals the bottom half of your original object.

[image]

After this, the object is sliced, and the modifiers are preserved on the objects.